# uvm connect analysis port using full path

Tags: uvm

I want to connect between monitors analysis port to scoreboard's export.
The monitor and SB are on different envs (m_env and sb_env)
The issue is that I don't want to connect the analysis port from the common higher hierarchy.
I want to use the full path to connect it from the SB env (sb_env) as:
*uvm_test.test_env.m_env.agent.monitor.ap.connect(uvm_test.test_env.sb_env.sb.imp)*
OR
*uvm_test.test_env.m_env.agent.monitor.ap.connect(sb.imp)*

is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I'm contractually obliged to tell you that this is a very bad idea. In doing this you will only make the scoreboard work in that environment, under that exact hierarchy. You should make your connections properly inside your `test_env`, as that's what it's there for.

If you still insist on doing this, here's some proto-code to get you started. You'll need to get the instance of the test:

```
uvm_root root = uvm_root::get();
uvm_test test_top = root.top_levels.pop_front();
```

You'll need to cast the `test_top` to your base test class (the one that defines the instance of the `test_env`:

```
my_test_base test_top_cast;
if (!$cast(test_top_cast, test_top)
  `uvm_fatal(...)
```

Now you can traverse your hierarchy downwards starting from`test_top_cast`.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for your answer. This is now clear to my I shouldn't do it :) It is also good to know how I should approach this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @yogevdamary I see you're new to the site. Welcome! You're supposed to accept answers you find useful to show that your question has been answered. Also, the moderators typically frown upon 'Thanks you!' style comments.